# Empty response by JQuery.ajax and object and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am stuck by creating my first universal code for ajax responses. I simply do not get an output here, neither in php nor in the ajax response. This must have something to be in the post data.

This is my ajax request:

```
        var info = {};
        //get id info
        info["ses-id"] = $("#theme").attr("scene");
        //get template info
        info["ses-template"] = $("#theme").attr("template");

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            type: "POST",
            url: "query.php"
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert (data);
            //window.location = "?szenen";
            console.log("Data sent.");
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("There was an error." + errorThrown);
        });
```

This is my query.php so far:

```
    <?php 
        $return = $_POST;
        $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
        print(json_encode($return));
```

The output is an object where only the json entry is filled with [].

The stringified variable looks good, it's a string like this:

```
    {"ses-id":"1","ses-template":"2"}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Where is the **succes** function?

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `json_decode`?

Comment: @Naruto succes(), error() and complete() are deprecated in JQuery 1.8

Comment: @Naruto From the jQuery docs: `An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method`

Comment: Alright, seems I've learned something new today :)

Comment: Try using var_dump($_POST); instead of the print function and see what you get. Alternatively, you can examine your xhr requests through the Chrome Developer console or something similar. You can see what is actually being sent and what the response is.

Comment: @Blaatpiraat No, I want to send data back from php to json.

Comment: @frost287 I already did that and edited the question. Seems the post is empty.

Comment: I get it. You have dataType: "json" but you are also using JSON.stringify. setting dataType: "json" tells jquery to stringify it for you, so in essence you are doing it twice.

Comment: @frost287 same without stringify :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataType and contentType both must be deactivated, then I got responses.

```
    $.ajax({
        //dataType: "json",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        type: "POST",
        url: "query.php"
```

Varying the info object results in varies of the php var but that wasn't my problem.

BIG thanks to everyone especially [CJ_Wurtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185383/cj-wurtz) who pushed me the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are sending a json encoded string as the POST body, and then using $_POST to access it.  $_POST is an array of key/value POST data.  Since your data doesn't have a key, you can't access it from the $_POST array.  It's just a value (a string value at that).

If you change your PHP script to be:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
?>
```

It will output the JSON you passed in.  Note that there is no need to do a `json_encode()` because the value is a string, not an array.  The json you passed it was never decoded.

Alternatively, if your javascript was:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(info) },
    type: "POST",
    url: "query.php"
})
```

then your post body would be:

```
data={"ses-id":"1","ses-template":"2"}
```

you could then do

```
<?php
echo $_POST["data"];
?>
```

Again noting the data you sent it was never decoded, so it's still just a string.  PHP does not json_decode for you.

Comment: I changed the line to `data: { "data": JSON.stringify(info) },`, but the $_POST["data"] is still empty. I don't get it.

Comment: Check if the `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` works.  Also updated my answer, removed the json data/content types defined.  Try without those defined

Comment: I am getting data (whoooho) but it seems urlencoded. I will try to get it into the post variable.

Comment: When you remove  `contentType` and `JSON.stringify`, like in my answer, then $_POST is normal array with those key value pairs as expected.

Comment: np, sorry i wasn't spot on, I assumed the jquery was correct and was just testing the POST call manually, and saw the data go through fine.  Also just checked the docs, don't remove the  `dataType: "json"` I said to, it's what decodes the json response

Answer (score 0):

It works when you drop contentType and JSON.stringify:

```
    var info = {};
    //get id info
    info["ses-id"] = $("#theme").attr("scene");
    //get template info
    info["ses-template"] = $("#theme").attr("template");

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: info,
        type: "POST",
        url: "query.php"
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       console.log(data);
        //window.location = "?szenen";
        console.log("Data sent.");
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("There was an error." + errorThrown);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, the result is that contentType and dataType must be removed.